# I've created a drop down menu with pure CSS and I want it to be drop-up not drop-down I can't figure out what to add or change to make it drop-up

Tags: html, css

I've created a drop down menu with pure CSS and I've gotten it to a place that I like EXCEPT I want it to be "drop-up" not drop-down since the menu bar is going at the bottom of the layout. I can't figure out what to add or change to make it "drop-up," help please!!

[image]

The CSS I used:

```
        #cssmenuf {
          position: relative;
          height: 50px;
          background: #2b2f3a;
          width: auto;
        }
        #cssmenuf ul {
          list-style: none;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          line-height: 1;
        }
        #cssmenuf > ul {
          position: relative;
          display: block;
          background: #2b2f3a;
          height: 32px;
          width: 100%;
          z-index: 500;
          bottom:100%;
        }
        #cssmenuf > ul > li {
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          float: left;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

        #cssmenuf ul li a {
          display: block;
          font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        #cssmenuf > ul > li > a {
          font-size: 12px;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 15px 20px;
          color: #7a8189;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
          -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
          -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
          -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
          transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
        }
        #cssmenuf > ul > li.has-subf > a {
          padding-right: 25px;
        }
        #cssmenuf > ul > li:hover > a {
          color: #ffffff;
        }
        #cssmenuf li.has-subf::after {
          display: block;
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
        }
        #cssmenuf > ul > li.has-subf::after {
          right: 10px;
          top: 20px;
          border: 5px solid transparent;
          border-top-color: #7a8189;
        }
        #cssmenuf > ul > li:hover::after {
          border-top-color: #ffffff;
        }

        #cssmenuf ul ul {
          position: absolute;
          left: -9999px;
          top: 70px;
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
          -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
          -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
          -o-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
          transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
          z-index: 1000;
        }
        #cssmenuf ul ul ul {
          top: 37px;
          padding-left: 5px;
        }
        #cssmenuf ul ul li {
          position: relative;
        }
        #cssmenuf > ul > li:hover > ul {
          left: auto;
          top: 44px;
          opacity: 1;
        }
        #cssmenuf ul ul li:hover > ul {
          left: 170px;
          top: 0;
          opacity: 1;
        }
        #cssmenuf ul ul li a {
          width: 130px;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          font-size: 12px;
          color: #9ea2a5;
          background: #fff;
          -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
          -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
          -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
          -o-transition: all .35s ease;
          transition: all .35s ease;
        }
        #cssmenuf ul ul li:hover > a {
          background: #f6f6f6;
          color: #8c9195;
        }
        #cssmenuf ul ul li:last-child > a,
        #cssmenu ul ul li.last > a {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }

        #cssmenuf ul ul li.has-subf::after {
          border: 4px solid transparent;
          border-left-color: #9ea2a5;
          right: 10px;
          top: 12px;
          -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
          -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
          -o-transition: all .2s ease;
          transition: all .2s ease;
          -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease, right 0.2s ease;
        }
        #cssmenuf ul ul li.has-subf:hover::after {
          border-left-color: #fff;
          right: -5px;
          -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
```

HTML

```
        <div id='cssmenuf'>
        <ul>
        <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>
        <span>About Us</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='active'><a href='#'>
         <span>FAQ</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='active'><a href='#'>
        <span>Contact Us</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='active'><a href='#'>
        <span>Testimonial</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-subf'><a href='#'><span>Share On</span></a>
        <ul>
        <li class='has-subf'><a href='#'>
        <span>Facebook</span></a></li>
        <li class='has-subf'><a href='#'>
        <span>Google+</span></a></li>
        <li class='has-subf'><a href='#'>
        <span>linkedIn</span></a></li>
        <li class='has-subf'><a href='#'>
        <span>Twitter</span></a></li>
        </ul></li>          
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: "Here's some code I found. It doesn't quite do what I want so can someone make it do what I want for me?" is how I ready your question. You need to show an actual attempt at achieving the specific behaviour you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "#cssmenuf ul ul" and "#cssmenuf > ul > li:hover > ul" you use "top" instead of "bottom" to position your element. Change "top: 70px;" to "bottom: 70px;" and "top: 44px;" to "bottom: 44px;" and it should work.